# Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<double?>' to 'double'

Tags: c#, type-conversion, nullable

I'm trying to get a double from database using entity framework, but I get an exception, below is my code

```
public static double GetFxRate(DateTime dt)    
{
  DBEntities dbe = new DBEntities ();
  var fx_rate = dbe.MyTable
       .Where (s => s.Currency == "aaaaaaaaa" && s.Date == dt)
       .Select (s => (s.ask + s.bid)/2);
  return Convert.ToDouble(fx_rate);
}
```

this code generate an exception in the last line

> Additional information: Impossible d'effectuer un cast d'un objet de type 'System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.DbQuery`1[System.Nullable`1[System.Double]]' en type 'System.IConvertible'

How can I correct this please?

Comment: `Select` means `fx_rate` is going to be the type of your table, did you want `First()`?

Comment: What are you trying to get? You have selected a list of numeric values (ints? doubles?). Do you want one of those values specifically? An average or summation?

Answer (score -1):

Try

```
public static double GetFxRate(DateTime dt)    
{
  DBEntities dbe = new DBEntities ();
var fx_rate = dbe.MyTable.Where (s => s.Currency == "aaaaaaaaa" && s.Date == dt).Select( s => (s.ask + s.bid)/2).FirstOrDefault();
return Convert.ToDouble(fx_rate);
}
```

The problem is `Select` returns an `IQueryable<Double>` which is all of the possible results but you're only expecting a single result so `FirstOrDefault` should work to get only one result.

Comment: Who will check null ? FirstOrDefault will give null if not found

Comment: I don't think that's going to compile as the expression you've passed to FirstOrDefault is not `Func<T,bool>`

Comment: I've edited it. I didn't look closely enough. It should work now.